# In react native, conditionally render an item in an array

Tags: arrays, react-native, formik

I have a Formik form in react native where I have a field array that has a series of questions.  One of the questions has a custom component that the user can select from and if they select 'changed any tyres' then another component appears. This is working great but I cannot seem to figure out how to be only specific to the array item they are in.  It appears in all array items.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={initialState}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}

        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        {props => (
          <Form>
            <View>
             <MyDatePicker
               label="Date"
               name="tsDate"
             />
              <FieldArray
                name="timesheets"
                render={arrayHelpers => (
                  <>
                    {props.values.timesheets &&
                      (
                        props.values.timesheets.map((timesheet, index) => (
                          <View>
                            <Select
                              label="Have you..."
                              name={`timesheets.[${index}].accessory`}
                              items={[
                                { label: 'N/A', value: 'N/A', key: 1 },
                                { label: 'useed a Light Vehicle', value: 'useed a Light Vehicle', key: 2 },
                                { label: 'changed any GET', value: 'changed any GET', key: 3 },
                                { label: 'changed any Tyres', value: 'changed any Tyres', key: 4 },
                                { label: 'used a Rock Breaker', value: 'used a Rock Breaker', key: 5 },
                                { label: 'used a Trailer', value: 'used a Trailer', key: 6 },
                                { label: 'used a GPS', value: 'used a GPS', key: 7 },
                              ]}
                            />

                            {(props.values.timesheets.some((timesheet) => (timesheet.accessory === ('changed any Tyres') )) ) 
                            ? 
                                <View>
                                  <Select
                                    label="What type of Tyres"
                                    name={`timesheets.[${index}].tyresType`}
                                    items={[
                                      { label: 'Front RH, LH', value: 'Front RH, LH', key: 1 },
                                      { label: 'Rear RH, LH', value: 'Rear RH, LH', key: 2 },
                                      { label: 'Spare', value: 'Spare', key: 3 },
                                    ]}
                                  />
                                </View>
                                : 
                                <View>
                                    {console.log('Hide Rock Breaker!')}
                                </View>
                            }
                            {props.values.timesheets.length === 1 ? (
                              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={cvstyles.arrayButtons} onPress={() => arrayHelpers.push(index, '')}>
                                  <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }} >Add Entry</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                              </View>
                            ) : (
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
                                  <TouchableOpacity style={cvstyles.arrayButtons} onPress={() => arrayHelpers.push(index, '')}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }} >Add Entry</Text>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                                  <TouchableOpacity style={[cvstyles.arrayButtons, { marginRight: '2%' }]} onPress={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }} >Remove Entry</Text>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                              )}
                          </View>
                  </>
                )}
              />
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep one array for `changeTyreSelectedOption = []` in state and if you user select change any tyre option then push that index to `changeTyreSelectedOption` array like this `changeTyreSelectedOption.push(index)`. Now condition to show extra component will be

```
{changeTyreSelectedOption.includes(index) 
                        ? 
                            <View>
                              <Select
                                label="What type of Tyres"
                                name={`timesheets.[${index}].tyresType`}
                                items={[
                                  { label: 'Front RH, LH', value: 'Front RH, LH', key: 1 },
                                  { label: 'Rear RH, LH', value: 'Rear RH, LH', key: 2 },
                                  { label: 'Spare', value: 'Spare', key: 3 },
                                ]}
                              />
                            </View>
                            : 
                            <View>
                                {console.log('Hide Rock Breaker!')}
                            </View>
                        }
```

to show the desired component.

**Note:** you also need to remove the `index` from the `changeTyreSelectedOption` if user change option

Comment: Thank you for your answer Awais.  I'm not sure how I would incorporate this in order to only show when 'changed any Tyres' is selected?